# PdfBox 2.0.0 write text at given postion in a page

Tags: java, pdf

I have just passed from PdfBox 1.8 to 2.0.0 and there are quite significant differences.
Before to write a text on an existing pdf page I used drawString.
In 2.0.0 draw string is deprecated but showText does not work in a block text.

My code in 1.8:

```
 contentStream.beginText()
 contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(250, 665)
 contentStream.drawString("1  2 3 4 5 6    7  8  9   1 0")
 contentStream.endText()
```

My code in 2.0

```
  PDDocument newPdf=null
  newPdf=PDDocument.load(sourcePdfFile)
  PDPage firstPage=newPdf.getPage(0)
  PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(newPdf, firstPage, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND,true,true)
 contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize)
 contentStream.beginText()
 contentStream.lineTo(200,685)
 contentStream.showText("John")
 contentStream.endText()
```

But it does not working...

Anyone has any idea about how can I write text as in 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Litttle late but its not allowed to use contentStream.lineTo(200,685) within a text block. You can use contentStream.newLineAtOffset(200, 685); and it will work.